# Create custom LocalChangeInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing an application using Spring Boot. In my application I am going to use localized URL smth like `http://localhost:8080/School/**en**/xxx/...` . I try to implement Custom Locale Interceptor. In listing below the first variant works fine. I would like to use the second variant but instead of France or Germany locale doesn't change and remains en_US. Can anybody please suggest me anything ?

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

1 VARIANT

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
    return slr;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}

2 VARIANT

@Bean
public LangInterceptor langInterceptor() {
    return new LangInterceptor();
}

    @Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor( langInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}
}
```

And my custom Interceptor:

```
public class LangInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
LocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver;
Locale locale;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(request.getServletPath(), "/it/")) {
        locale = new Locale("it");
    } else {
        locale = new Locale("en");
    }
    sessionLocaleResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.FRENCH);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

}
}
```

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation is completely  truly, but:
1. LocaleChangeInterceptor is from package `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n` and is avised to use and it works as all first variant.
2. The second variant worked for me when it was written in xml.

Comment: I need exactly that my locale would be managed from url

Comment: that's exactly what I said in my answer. If you do as it asks for, and doesn't work, then let me know. If you don't do it, then I don't know why you're here asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First variant will work if I just add in my configuration file LocaleChangeInterceptor. The reason looks like LocaleResolver doesn't initialize without interceptor, but spring docs says that every class has default constructor. So it works.

```
@Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't throw in a random `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to change the locale. Spring uses `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` by default and you want to resolve based on path segment. Extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, then do the following:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
   // return custom LocaleResolver
}
```

However, I'm cautioning you that you're going against the HTTP spec. The `Accept-Language` header is meant for this purpose, which is what the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` uses.

You don't need a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` because it operates on a query parameter.